# Breadcrumb menu duplicates link when query string is parsed

Tags: php, regex, breadcrumbs

I've created a breadcrumb menu which get's the page URL, `explodes` the text after each trailing slash (after the domain) and prints it out.

This works fine if no query string is added to the URL, however, once a query is added, it duplicates the link:

**Working example:**

```
<?php
    $url = "/parent/child";
    // 1. Get URL
    $crumbs = explode("/", trim($url, '/'));
    // 2. Strip extras
    $build = '';
    // 3. Define int so last item is not a link
    $lastKey = count($crumbs) - 1;
    // 4. Execute loop
    foreach($crumbs as $key => $crumb){
        $build .= '/'.$crumb;
        // format text 
        $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
        $crumb = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $crumb); // remove dashes
        $crumb = trim($crumb); // remove whitespace from before and after string

        $pagename = "child";  

        echo $key < $lastKey
            ? "$crumb /" : $pagename;
    }
?>
```

The above outputs: **Parent / child**

Which is fine.

However, now the second test with a query string (notice the `$url`):

```
<?php
    $url = "/parent/child/?=query-string";
    // 1. Get URL
    $crumbs = explode("/", trim($url, '/'));
    // 2. Strip extras
    $build = '';
    // 3. Define int so last item is not a link
    $lastKey = count($crumbs) - 1;
    // 4. Execute loop
    foreach($crumbs as $key => $crumb){
        $build .= '/'.$crumb;
        // format text 
        $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
        $crumb = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $crumb); // remove dashes
        $crumb = trim($crumb); // remove whitespace from before and after string

        $pagename = "parent";  

        echo $key < $lastKey
            ? "$crumb   /" : $pagename;
    }
?>
```

This outputs: **Parent / Child / parent**
Expected output: **Parent / Child **

I understand that I've set `$pagename = "parent"`, but I want it to ignore query strings.

**I've tried the following:**

```
$crumbs = explode("/", trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/'));
$crumbs = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $crumbs);
```

Still same results.

**Latest code:**

```
<?php

    // 1. Get current URL
    $crumbs = trim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    $crumbs = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $crumbs);
    $crumbs = explode("/", $crumbs);
    array_filter($crumbs);


    $count = count($crumbs);
    $build = '';

    // 3. Define int so last item is not a link
    $lastKey = count($crumbs) - 1;

    // 4. Execute loop
    foreach($crumbs as $key => $crumb){
        $build .= $crumb;

        // format text 
        $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
        $crumb = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $crumb); // remove dashes
        $crumb = trim($crumb); // remove whitespace from before and after string

        $pagename = get_query_var('pagename');  
        $pagename = the_title('', '', false); // print page name as is in WP
        $pagename = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $pagename); // remove dashes
        $pagename = trim($pagename);

        echo $key < $lastKey
            ? "<a class='crumbLink' href=".$build.">".$crumb."</a>
               <span class='slash'>/</span>"
            : $pagename;

    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in:

`echo $key < $lastKey ? "$crumb   /" : $pagename;`

In the step 3:

```
// 3. Define int so last item is not a link
$lastKey = count($crumbs) - 1;
```

If you have 3 items, $lastKey will be 2 because, you count 3 items and you substract 1.

Later in the loop, the last item will be in the $key = 2, so:

```
$key = 2 < $lastKey = 2
```

Comment: Hmm, I've ran some tests and think so too. Is there a way I can make it dynamic? I.e. I don't want to current page (last item in the breadcrumb) to be a link and want it to ignore any query strings. I've tried to use regex to remove the query from the URL `$crumbs = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $crumbs);` however, I'm still seeing the same results?

Comment: @Freddy if you don't want the query strings, you could use explode with the symbol "?" and use the first array as your $crumbs.
If I understood correctly.

Comment: What I want is 1. Get URL, 2. Explode that URL (after each `/`) to get all the slugs 3. Make all the slugs link off to there pages, except the last slug (which will be the current page the user is on). The issue is of course, when a query string is passed, it duplicates the second last slug (which I don't want)

Answer (score 0):

How about we remove query string from the **$url**.

```
<?php
    $url ="/parent/child/";
    $url_arr = parse_url($url);
    if(isset($url_arr['query'])){
    $query = $url_arr['query'];
    $url = str_replace(array($query,'?'), '', $url);
    }
    // 1. Get URL
    $crumbs = explode("/", trim($url, '/'));
    // 2. Strip extras
    $build = '';
    // 3. Define int so last item is not a link
    $lastKey = count($crumbs) - 1;
    // 4. Execute loop
    foreach($crumbs as $key => $crumb){
        $build .= '/'.$crumb;
        // format text
        $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
        $crumb = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $crumb); // remove dashes
        $crumb = trim($crumb); // remove whitespace from before and after string

        $pagename = "parent";

        echo $key < $lastKey
            ? "$crumb   /" : $pagename;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've tried `$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; $url_arr = parse_url($url); $query = $url_arr['query'];` but getting `Undefined index: query` error?

Comment: I have edited the post the error was coming on URLs where no query string was present but now it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stick with your first 'working' solution but use `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)` instead of the `$url` directly:

```
<?php
    $url = parse_url("/parent/child?foo=bla&bar=bla", PHP_URL_PATH));
    // 1. Get URL
    $crumbs = explode("/", trim($url, '/'));
    // 2. Strip extras
    $build = '';
    // 3. Define int so last item is not a link
    $lastKey = count($crumbs) - 1;
    // 4. Execute loop
    foreach($crumbs as $key => $crumb){
        $build .= '/'.$crumb;
        // format text 
        $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
        $crumb = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $crumb); // remove dashes
        $crumb = trim($crumb); // remove whitespace from before and after string

        $pagename = "child";  

        echo $key < $lastKey
            ? "$crumb /" : $pagename;
    }
?>
```

Check more details about `parse_url()` in the manual: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php